# Using nested for loops to print numbers (java)

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, printing

I am trying to use nested for loops (java) to print out the following:

```
331
330
322
311
300
222
111
```

and I am having some trouble. So far I have:

```
for(int a = 3; a >=0; a--)
{
    for(int b = 3; b>=0; b--)
    {
        for(int c = 2; c>=0; c--)
        {
            System.out.println(a + " "+ b +" "+ c);
        }
    }
}
```

but that prints out something more like this:

```
3 3 2
3 3 1
3 3 0
3 2 2
3 2 1
3 2 0
3 1 2
3 1 1
3 1 0
3 0 2
3 0 1
3 0 0
2 3 2
2 3 1
2 3 0
2 2 2
2 2 1
2 2 0
2 1 2
```

What is wrong with my code? How can I get it to print out the first sequence, not the second? I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the middle loop, but I'm really not sure.

Thanks!

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a discernable pattern to your desired output.

Comment: what do you mean by first sequence

Comment: Can you describe your request precisely. From this output we can't figure what should have to produce this output. Is this output complete? Or there can be more elements? Your solution gives more than your request.

Comment: @BoskoMijin I know my solution gives more-- I am trying to make it so that my code prints out the first data and ONLY the first data. I'm not quite sure why that's so hard to understand.

Comment: It's hard to understand because you don't specify what those numbers *mean* (why those and not others?). That's called a **pattern**. For example: 2,4,6,8 have a pattern: they're all even numbers. Hope you understood.

Comment: @m0skit0 the pattern is that the "c" number goes down by one every time (210 210 210) and it repeats, the "b" number goes down by one and starts repeating the same (210 210 210) pattern when the "c" number hits 0, and the "a" number goes down by one and starts repeating it once the "b" number hits 0. PLEASE HELP ME SOMEBODY

Comment: If the last number counts 2 1 0, why do you expect it to start at 1?

Comment: I still don't understand how `222 111` fits into your described pattern, and why counting starts again at 2 like `331 330 322`.

Comment: @drw85 because the 2 is imaginary, 210 is just the pattern

Comment: for(int c = 2; c>=0; c--) How's that two imaginary?

Comment: @drw85 that 2 isn't imaginary-- the two in the sequence I WANT to print out is imaginary. UGH I NEED HELP

Comment: So sometimes going from one number to the other only one digit changes (331 -> 330), sometimes two digits (330 -> 322) and sometimes all three (300 -> 222). Either you can describe precise rules for how all three digits correlate to each other or nobody will be able to help you. One thing is certain: You can not do this without checking *more than one* digit in the conditions for the loops.

Comment: You should consider doing something else if you're so annoyed by finding solutions to problems. And you most likely won't find much help, when you're not even willing to provide any helpful information.

Answer (score 0):

If you have nested for loops, unless you set the limits on the inner loops based on the values of the variables in the outer loops, the pattern generated by the inner loops (second and third numbers, in this case) is gonna be the same in each iteration of the outer loop.

I can't code right now, but it seems to me that if you set b to run from a to zero, instead of from 3 to zero you might get a little closer to what you want.

But still, since it seems there isn't a pattern in what you want to get, it's hard to think of an algorithm to print them. What do these numbers mean?